# Can't Increase CameraX ImageAnalysis Resolution Past 1024x768

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera2, android-camerax

I cannot seem to get my CameraX camera to give me an ImageAnalysis resolution of anything larger than 1024x768

Here is my set up

```
def cameraXVersion = "1.0.0-rc02"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$cameraXVersion"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$cameraXVersion"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha21"
```

```
val imageAnalyzer = cameraFrameAnalyzer?.let { analyzer ->
    ImageAnalysis.Builder()
        .setTargetResolution(Size(1080, 1440)) // also tried Size(1440, 1080), no change
        .setMaxResolution(Size(1440, 1440))
        .setTargetRotation(cameraXStartOrientation ?: cameraPreviewOrientation)
        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
        .build().apply {
            setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, GenericAnalyzer(analyzer))
        }
}

...

// commented out all other use cases to make sure they're not interfering
cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
    lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, /*preview, imageCapture,*/ imageAnalyzer
)
```

I also later will alter the rotation on the imageAnalysis use case if the device orientation changes, not sure if that could mess things up somehow. Commenting it out has no effect

```
override fun updateRotation(orientation: DeviceRotationHelper.Orientation) {
    super.updateRotation(orientation)
    val cameraXRotation = orientation.toCameraXOrientation()

    imageCapture?.targetRotation = cameraXRotation
    imageAnalysis?.targetRotation = cameraXRotation
}
```

According to this code 1440x1080 is in the list of output sizes (and nowhere near the largest), and it is less than the 1080p maximum set for CameraX:

```
val characteristics = Camera2CameraInfo.extractCameraCharacteristics(camera!!.cameraInfo)
val streamConfigurationMap = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
val outputSizes = streamConfigurationMap!!.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
println(outputSizes)
```

According to the characteristics, my device is a LEVEL_3

```
characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL) == CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_3 // true
```

According to this documentation, this is the highest level listed https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the model of your device? BTW Size(1440, 1080) is the correct one.

Comment: did you manage to fix this?